# Problems with the properties OSK.EXE (On Screen KeyBoard) +POWERSHELL +REGEDIT

Tags: windows, powershell, regedit, on-screen-keyboard

as the title indicates I need help with the on-screen keyboard properties.

I have to configure a script, which I will deploy through SCCM in 30 terminals, and I need to make the keyboard go on screen as soon as I start the pc.

I have already solved this by adding this key to the registry

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run Clavier_Visuel = "C:\Windows\System32\osk.exe"
```

The problem is that I can't find a place to set the parameters of the keyboard: Remove the X to close it, display the PAD number, set the language to French and make it fit the screen.

This can be done manually, but that's not the goal.

Another point is that different users will be logged into the computers, so I can't set the condition to single user, but it should be general for all.

If you can help me it would be great, since I have not found anything useful so far, a greeting!

Comment: The settings are in the registry HKCU only - looks like you'd have to run a script each time a user logs in to change them before osk launches. Probably best to run this via Group Policy.